# Does "this" and "these" belong to the same lexeme?

Tags: morphology, inflection, derivation, lexemes

I am confused as to whether "this" and "these" belong to the same lexeme

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme) article begins:"A lexeme (/ˈlɛksiːm is a unit of lexical meaning that underlies a set of words that are related through inflection." Does that not answer your question?

Comment: It might if there were a common meaning of _underlies_. The fact is that any technical term can be defined any way at all. _Lexeme_ can be defined to include _this_ and _these_ in one lexeme, or as two. Demonstratives like _this_ have little or no lexical meaning, which is the point of "lexemes". _Run_ is a lexeme in _runner, running, runs, ran_ because they have related meanings; _this_ has no meaning at all outside a deictic context. It's not what you'd call a "lexical item", like you could _runner_.

Comment: @Luna. I would say yes. "Lexeme" is defined as 'a unit corresponding to a word seen abstractly enough to include all of its **inflectional forms**, e.g. _take_, _takes_, _took_, _taken_ and _taking_ are the forms of the lexeme **take**’. Similarly with nouns: the plural form _friends_ is an inflectional form of the lexeme _friend_.  It follows that the determinative _these_ is the plural form of the lexeme _this_.